# How can i change default Outlook 2016 send, draft, junk, Archives folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-outlook-2019

i want to change my default send, draft, junk and archives email location just like Thunderbird but in Outlook2016 and 2019. I searched a lot and try everything but i did not find anything.
Can please someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! You should elaborate what you mean by "like Thunderbolt: for people like me who dont use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Reddy said above, some users do not use Thunderbolt. So, to better understand and solve your issue, please provide us with more information related to your issue.

As I know, the default folders of your email account in Outlook are usually based on your mail server. In Outlook client, we could only uncheck "Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder" via File > Options > Mail and use Outlook rules to move copies to other folders you want. But there is no such options for draft, junk and archive folders.

What's more, according to my research, if you are using Exchange email account, the MFCMAPI tool may help you rename the default folders, for more information, please check this article: [Rename the default folders](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/renamedefaultfolders.htm).